Time to decision/uncommunicative Journal
My co-authors and I submitted a paper to the Journal of Ichthyology and Herpetology at the end of February. We have not heard anything from them about the stage of our submission in the review process, despite an email to the editor at the beginning of April. We have only gotten a response from one associate editor after a mass email to them in an attempt to find out if it had been assigned to someone. At this point, we are over the average time to decision that the journal themselves highlights (http://www.ichthyologyandherpetology.org/blog).
Does anyone have experience with the recent publication process of Ichthyology and Herpetology/Copeia, or attempts to communicate with them? The most experienced PI on our team is growing increasingly restless with them. My worry is that even if we tell them we are retracting the article, they won't acknowledge it.

This seems like a question so specialized that the likelihood that anyone here actually knows is approximately zero.

Also related: Do I need to wait for a journal to "consent" to paper withdrawal before submitting elsewhere?
